# how to fadein an inline element as a block element

Tags: jquery, css, fadein

I want to fade in an anchor element, but I want it to be a block element

```
.main_cat_hover {display:none; height:124px; line-height:22px; padding:10px; position:absolute; top:0px; z-index:1;}

$('#main_cat_list li').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).children('.main_cat_hover').stop(true,true).css('display','block').fadeIn();
});
```

However, if I use `css('display','block')` then it will simply display without fading in, and if I remove the css, then the element simply will not look right.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something utilizing [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

From the docs:

> The matched elements will be hidden immediately, with no animation.
>   This is roughly equivalent to calling .css( "display", "none" ),
>   except that the value of **the display property is saved in jQuery's
>   data cache so that display can later be restored** to its initial
>   value. If an element has a display value of inline and is hidden then
>   shown, it will once again be displayed inline.

```
$(this).children('.main_cat_hover')
    .stop(true,true)
    .css('display','block')
    .hide()
    .fadeIn();
});
```

While there are likely **better ways** to achieve this, given the info provided, this seems like the simplest.

Note that `visibility: hidden` will preserve the "space" the elements take, but they will not be visible - so this could (or could not) be a viable option.

Here it is in a [Simple Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dgbh3t3x/)

Comment: yes, simple of course, should have thought of that.